# Celery tasks doesn't works

Tags: python, django, celery

Celery docs say that Celery 3.1 can work with django out of box. But tasks not working. I have tasks.py:

```
from celery import task
from datetime import timedelta

@task.periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(seconds=20), ignore_result=True)
    def disable_not_confirmed_users():
        print "start"
```

Configs:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS = True
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://guest@localhost//'
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = 'project-queue'
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE = 'project-queue'
CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY = 'project-queue'
CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('project-queue', Exchange('project-queue'), routing_key='project-queue'),
)
```

project/celery.py
    from **future** import absolute_import

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

from django.conf import settings


app = Celery('project')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Run celery: `celery -A project worker --loglevel=INFO`

But nothing not happend.

Comment: celery work, but task doesn't run

Comment: Try to run celery as celery -A fratchy worker -B --loglevel=INFO

Comment: instead of print, try using the logging module to log an INFO mesage

Comment: Dima Kudosh, right. It helped.

Comment: Have you been running `celery beat`? Workers are to execute tasks, but `celery beat` is what puts the periodic tasks in queue for execution when their time ticks.

Answer (score 1):

you should use celery beat to run periodic task.

```
celery -A project worker --loglevel=INFO
```

starts the worker, which does the actually work.

```
celery -A proj beat
```

starts the beat service, which asks the work to do the job.